# dropdown menu exceeds container width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu. The problem is that my dropdown menu width exceeds container width. As far as i can see i have no margins or something similar.

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1020px;
    height: 1500px; 
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#wrapper1 {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;    
    position: relative; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1a1b20;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Roboto;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
.dropdown-menu > li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 340px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper1">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
            <li>A</li>       
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ul with class `dropdown-menu` has default padding/indent that pushes the content out of the container.

Add this css rule to your `.dropdown-menu`:

```
padding: 0;
```

Try it in the snippet:

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 1020px;
    height: 1500px; 
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#wrapper1 {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;    
    position: relative; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1a1b20;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Roboto;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
.dropdown-menu > li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 340px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper1">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
            <li>A</li>       
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But default padding; I thought css defines only such things

Comment: _“But default padding; I thought css defines only such things”_ – browsers have a default stylesheet they apply, and it usually includes default margins/paddings for lists and/or list items. If you don’t like those defaults, you have to override them yourself. You might want to look into “CSS Resets” – those are stylesheets that you can use that override those defaults (which may differ between browsers) with values that for most cases are considered to be sensible defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 1020px;
    height: 1500px; 
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#wrapper1 {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;    
    position: relative; 
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1a1b20;
    height: 40px;
    width: 980px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
.dropdown-menu > li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 307px;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper1">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu"  id="dropdown-menu"> 
        <li>A</li>       
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
</div>
```